# R: how to write lapply correctly to intersect polygons instead of FOR loop?

Tags: r, apply

I try to intersect list of polygons `poly.list` with polygon (SPFD) `b` by `raster::intersect(x,y)`

I want to apply the same process for the bunch of polygons, thus I've written for loop code. However, it takes an eternity to get my results back, so I wander how to apply one of *apply family to make it work?

here is my for loop:

```
int.list<-list()
for (i in 1:length(Poly.list.bb.from06)) {
  my.int<-intersect(poly.list[[i]], b)
  int.list[[i]]<-my.int
}
```

and here is my lapply function (as I want to apply `intersect` on list of multiple polygons and get back list of polygons as well)

```
int.list<-lapply(poly.list, intersect(poly.list, b))

int.list<-lapply(poly.list, function(x) intersect(poly.list, b))
```

Please, how can I write lapply correctly to do my intersection? Thank you !

Here are some dummy data:

```
# stack overflow
library(rgeos)

# create polygon
p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((2 2,-2 2,-2 -2,2 -2,2 2))")
# create two buffers - one wth {raster}, one with {rgeos},
# both covers also original polygon !
p2<-readWKT("POLYGON((1.5 1.5,-1.5 1.5,-1.5 -1.5,1.5 -1.5,1.5 1.5))")

poly.list<-list(p1, p2)

b = readWKT("POLYGON((1 1,-1 1,-1 -1,1 -1,1 1))")
```

Comment: `int.list<-lapply(poly.list, function(x) intersect(x, b))` but I don't believe it will get any quicker

Comment: Please provide a sample `poly.list` and `b` to reproduce

Comment: @HubertL, I think this doesn't work... :(

Comment: with error  `Error in as.vector(y) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @HubertL answer, this one is the one I'm looking for...

```
int.list2<-lapply(poly.list, function(x) intersect(x, b))
```

whole code:

```
# stack overflow
library(rgeos)

# create polygon
p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((2 2,-2 2,-2 -2,2 -2,2 2))")
# create two buffers - one wth {raster}, one with {rgeos},
# both covers also original polygon !
p2<-readWKT("POLYGON((1.5 1.5,-1.5 1.5,-1.5 -1.5,1.5 -1.5,1.5 1.5))")

poly.list<-list(p1, p2)

b = readWKT("POLYGON((1 1,-1 1,-1 -1,1 -1,1 1))")

# intersect list of polygons with a polygon,
# get back list of polygons
int.list2<-lapply(poly.list, function(x) intersect(x, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

`gIntersects()` is the function you are looking for:

```
sapply(poly.list, function(x) gIntersects(x, b))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: I think that no... I know that my polygons are intersection, but I want to extract the area which is actually intersected (common by both).  Running this, I get back logical values but I don't get back list of my intersected polygons...

Comment: If you want the intersection then use `gIntersections()`